Could not find the dlcdownload element
I use THIS code for docker bot testing but I get this error: Could not find the dlcdownload element
Could not find the dlcdownload element.
2024-04-01 00:20:12,268 - werkzeug - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2024 00:20:12] "GET /test/filecrypt.cc/Container/F21C754A83.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2024-04-01 00:20:35,966 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - Entering: get_me
2024-04-01 00:20:35,975 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - {'can_read_all_group_messages': False, 'supports_inline_queries': False, 'username': 'filecyptsoffitta_bot', 'is_bot': True, 'can_join_groups': True, 'id': 7062873875, 'first_name': 'filecrypt'}
2024-04-01 00:20:35,975 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - Exiting: get_me
2024-04-01 00:20:35,975 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - Entering: send_message
2024-04-01 00:20:36,014 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - {'entities': [{'offset': 31, 'length': 5, 'type': 'bot_command'}], 'caption_entities': [], 'delete_chat_photo': False, 'chat': {'username': 'Peter_****', 'first_name': 'Peter', 'type': 'private', 'id': 12*****}, 'text': 'Inserisci un URL FileCrypt con /link <url>', 'new_chat_members': [], 'photo': [], 'date': 1711930835, 'message_id': 58, 'new_chat_photo': [], 'channel_chat_created': False, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'group_chat_created': False, 'from': {'username': 'filecypt******_bot', 'is_bot': True, 'id': 70******, 'first_name': 'filecrypt'}}
2024-04-01 00:20:36,014 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - Exiting: send_message
2024-04-01 00:20:36,014 - werkzeug - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2024 00:20:36] "POST /7062873875:AAGSeNq_0sKu5psGLEKwcFyRTCqYy_9LZ6g HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2024-04-01 00:20:41,086 - root - DEBUG - Processing https://filecrypt.cc/Container/F21C754A83.html...
2024-04-01 00:20:41,087 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): filecrypt.cc:443
2024-04-01 00:20:41,461 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://filecrypt.cc:443 "GET /Container/F21C754A83.html HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Could not find the dlcdownload element.
2024-04-01 00:20:41,467 - werkzeug - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2024 00:20:41] "POST /7062873875:AAGSeNq_0sKu5psGLEKwcFyRTCqYy_9LZ6g HTTP/1.1" 200 -

This is strange because I I don't get this error in this standalone code running from terminal (locally) and I get urls from filecrypt links without problems but it fails when runs inside a Docker container.  https://imgur.com/F1IuRpd.png
I test this url: https://filecrypt.cc/Container/F21C754A83.html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def get_links(filecrypt_url):
    response = requests.get(filecrypt_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    if "/Link/" in filecrypt_url:
        script = soup.find_all('script')[-1].string
        start = script.rfind('http')
        end = script.find('id=', start) + 43
        link = script[start:end].replace('&amp;', '&')
        return [link]
    elif "/Container/" in filecrypt_url:
        dlcdownload_element = soup.find('button', class_='dlcdownload')
        if dlcdownload_element is None:
            print("Could not find the dlcdownload element.")
            return []
        dlc_id = dlcdownload_element['onclick'].split("'")[1]
        dlc_url = f"https://{filecrypt_url.split('/')[2]}/DLC/{dlc_id}.dlc"
        dlc_response = requests.get(dlc_url)
        dcrypt_url = "http://dcrypt.it/decrypt/paste"
        dcrypt_data = {"content": dlc_response.text}
        dcrypt_response = requests.post(dcrypt_url, data=dcrypt_data)
        dcrypt_json = json.loads(dcrypt_response.text)
        return dcrypt_json['success']['links']

def main():
    print("Enter FileCrypt URLs (one per line, end with an empty line):")
    filecrypt_urls = []
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line:
            filecrypt_urls.append(line)
        else:
            break

    for filecrypt_url in filecrypt_urls:
        print(f"Processing {filecrypt_url}...")
        links = get_links(filecrypt_url)
        for link in links:
            print(link)
        print()

main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

